# file max size change

Tags: php, content-management-system, filesize

Have something like this, how to change max file size?

> /**    * Set Maximum File Size     *   * @access  public   *
>   @param    integer      * @return  void     */     function set_max_filesize($n)
>     {       $this->max_size = ((int) $n < 0) ? 0: (int) $n;     }

Answer (score 1):

You question was not clear but still am helping you out. If you are using **HTACCESS** then it can be easy done using **.htaccess**. Paste the 2 lines below. Change 4M to your desired value. Hope this helps.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4M
php_value post_max_size 4M
```

Comment: I have something like this in htacces:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^informacjecookiespopup\.html$ - [PT,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(index.php|images|files|robots.txt|system|user_guide|panel)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: Okay, paste the above line at the very end of the .htaccess file and it should work.

Comment: ```but still [I] am helping you out``` is the very spirit I wish we could see more often. This should be encouraged.